# Python Audio Analysis, Spectrogram: Which spectrogram should I use and why?

Tags: python, audio, conv-neural-network, spectrogram

I am doing my final project at university: pitch estimation from song recording using convolutional neural network (CNN). I want to retrieve pitches existed in a song recording. For CNN input, I am using a spectrogram.

I am using [MIR-QBSH dataset](http://mirlab.org/dataset/public/) with pitch vectors as data label. Before processing the audio to CNN (each audio has 8 sec duration in `.wav` files of 8 KHz, 8 bit, mono), I need to pre-process the audio into a spectrogram representation.

I have found 3 ways to generate a spectrogram, the code are listed below.
Audio example I am using in this code is available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17mjitC1dRruPH-u7HgJNXV8HajH8jwc8/view?usp=sharing).

Imports:

```
import librosa
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import librosa.display
from numpy.fft import *
import math
import wave
import struct
from scipy.io import wavfile
```

**Spectrogram A**

```
x, sr = librosa.load('audio/00020_2003_person1.wav', sr=None)

window_size = 1024
hop_length = 512 
n_mels = 128
time_steps = 384 

window = np.hanning(window_size)
stft= librosa.core.spectrum.stft(x, n_fft = window_size, hop_length = hop_length, window=window)
out = 2 * np.abs(stft) / np.sum(window)

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4))
ax = plt.axes()
plt.set_cmap('hot')
librosa.display.specshow(librosa.amplitude_to_db(out, ref=np.max), y_axis='log', x_axis='time',sr=sr)
plt.savefig('spectrogramA.png', bbox_inches='tight', transparent=True, pad_inches=0.0 )
```

**Spectrogram B**

```
x, sr = librosa.load('audio/00020_2003_person1.wav', sr=None)
X = librosa.stft(x)
Xdb = librosa.amplitude_to_db(abs(X))
# plt.figure(figsize=(14, 5))
librosa.display.specshow(Xdb, sr=sr, x_axis='time', y_axis='hz')
```

**Spectrogram C**

```
# Read the wav file (mono)
samplingFrequency, signalData = wavfile.read('audio/00020_2003_person1.wav')
print(samplingFrequency)
print(signalData)

# Plot the signal read from wav file
plt.subplot(111)
plt.specgram(signalData,Fs=samplingFrequency)
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
```

Spectrogram results are displayed below:
[image: Spectrogram Results]

My question is, from the 3 spectrograms I have listed above, which spectrogram is best to use for input to CNN and why should I use that spectrogram type? I am currently having difficulty to find their differences, as well as their pros and cons.